# onItemSelected / setOnItemSelectedListener not triggering

Tags: android

> > I am opening spiiner with onclick on button but my spinner is not
> >     trigger setOnItemSelectedListener this portion of code is not working   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View arg1,
> >     int pos,
> >                                     long id) {
> >                                 language = AppConstants.Language_arr[pos];
>
> ```
>                     }
>                     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
>                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>                     } spinner opens but onitemselected is not working
> ```

```
import com.privy.constants.AppConstants;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.Spinner;
            import android.widget.ToggleButton;

            public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
                private Spinner sp_languge, sp_login;
                private ToggleButton toggle_news_letter;
                private String language;
                private Button language_change;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
                    sp_languge = new Spinner(this);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_language = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            Settings.this, R.layout.spinner_item, AppConstants.Language_arr);
                    sp_languge.setAdapter(adapter_language);
                    language_change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.language_change);
                    language_change.setOnClickListener(this);
                    sp_languge.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                                long id) {
                            language = AppConstants.Language_arr[pos];

                        }
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                }
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (v == language_change) {

                        sp_languge.performClick();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: almost looks same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915432/onitemselectedlistener-not-being-called-for-my-spinner

Comment: add the spiiner on XMl with width zero...................

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555549/android-spinner-performclick-onitemselected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the spiiner on XMl with width/height zero...................

and use

```
sp_languge = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.<my_spinerid>);
```

[android spinner performClick onItemSelected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555549/android-spinner-performclick-onitemselected)

Comment: Thanks Dheeresh, Now I am using

in my xml It is working fine. but do not use android:visibility="gone" otherwise it will not work.

Thanks Ashwani